# Nginx 404 for /rails/active_storage/blobs/*filename(extension)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rails-activestorage, trix, actiontext

Below is my AWS NGINX config file. I am using rich text with active storage in my new rails app after upload when i am trying to open a file it gives me 404 error in production where in development it works really fine.

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |

      upstream backend {
        server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      log_format logd '$msec"$uri"'
                      '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                      '$http_x_forwarded_for';

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

      }

      server {
        listen 443;
        charset UTF-8;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier


        root /var/app/current/public;    

        # try_files $uri/index.html $uri /deploy/$uri /deploy/$uri.html /deploy/$uri.js @puma;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour logd;


        # 413 Request Entity Too Large
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

        location / {
          try_files $uri /deploy/$uri /deploy/$uri.html /deploy/$uri.js @puma;
        }


        location @puma{
          proxy_pass http://backend;
          # proxy_pass http://backend; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          proxy_buffers 8 32k;
          proxy_buffer_size 64k;

          proxy_redirect off;
          #break;
        }

        location /assets {
          alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
          allow all;
        }

        location ~ \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot|otf|pdf)$ {
          expires max;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|pdf)$ {
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2592000";
        }



        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
          return 405;
        }

        if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
          return 503;
        }
      }
```

Whenever i open [Link with file extension](https://staging.workrowd.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaWxsWkdObE9XWTVOaTB4WlRZNUxUUXhPV1F0T1RCbU5TMWhZMlF6T0RCak1UaGlOV0VHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2JfaWQifX0=--d2adcd6b48d914d8acc15785c925f99c8befdf8b/Employee-Resource-Group-group-2018.jpg) it shows me 404 error but if i open the same link without file extension it works [Link without file extension](https://staging.workrowd.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaWxsWkdObE9XWTVOaTB4WlRZNUxUUXhPV1F0T1RCbU5TMWhZMlF6T0RCak1UaGlOV0VHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2JfaWQifX0=--d2adcd6b48d914d8acc15785c925f99c8befdf8b/Employee-Resource-Group-group-2018). Not sure what i am doing wrong please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the below blocks in your Nginx, this might fix it

```
location ~ \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot|otf|pdf)$ {
  gzip_static on;
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  expires max;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|pdf)$ {
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2592000";
}
```